# Not able to delete a row in Angular using splice()

Tags: angular, typescript

In my code, I am fetching row data from my `TypeScript` file and I have added `2 buttons per row` through my `HTML`. I wish to delete a row using `splice()` but to no avail. Can anybody explain why the delete fails?

**HTML File**

```
<h2>Set Properties</h2>
  <hr>
  <br>
  <table class="table">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="order">ID</th>
        <th class="order">Key</th>
        <th class="order">Value</th>
        <th class="order">Edit</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor='let schedule of scheduleList; let i = index'>
        <td>{{schedule.id}}</td>
        <td>{{schedule.key}}</td>
        <td>{{schedule.value}}</td>
        <td>
          <a class="btn btn-success"><span class="fa fa-edit"></span></a>
          <br>
          <br>
          <a class="btn btn-danger" onClick="removeRow(i)"><span class="fa fa-trash"></span></a>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**TypeScript File**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'MyFirstAngularApplication-example',
  styleUrls: [ './example.component.scss' ],
  templateUrl: './example.component.html'
})

export class ExampleComponent {

  scheduleList : any[] = [
    {
      "id"    : "1",
      "key"   : "Pricing Key",
      "value" : "Daily Official"  
    },
    {
      "id"    : "2",
      "key"   : "Eligibility Key",
      "value" : "EOD"  
    }
  ]

  removeRow(num) {
    this.scheduleList.splice(num, 1);
  }
}
```

Am I making an error with a click as code completion throws `ng-click` as an option as well?

Comment: Is your `num` value is getting properly ??

Comment: It’s possible angular isn’t detecting the array change. Can you trigger change detection manually to see if that makes it work?

Comment: @yurzui is right. Could you write it as an answer?

Comment: Instead of onClick it should be (click) as yurzui commented

Answer (score 4):

THe correct syntax for angular is

```
(click)="removeRow(i)"
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use (click) instead of **`onClick`**

```
(click)="removeRow(i)"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `on-click` alternative syntax. see [Binding Syntax](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#binding-syntax-an-overview)

Comment: plus 1 for, `on-click` , kind of different :)